# how can i reduce the top and bottom space in receipt printing using thermal printer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, receipt

i am developing a small code for receipt printing using html, JavaScript and css. i am printing a certain div only in my page. but when i print in receipt the top having some space. i want to remove that space.

so here some codes i was tried but i don't know can i reduce or remove that.

so anyone help on this!!!

[![this is my printed receipt sample. i was marked which space i want to remove in that ][1]][1]

````
<head>
    <style>
        @media print
      {
         @page {
           margin-top: 0;
           margin-bottom: 0;
          
         }
         #div_print  {
           padding-top: 0px;
           padding-bottom: 0px ;
         }
      }
        </style>
    <script language="javascript">
        function printdiv(div_print) {
            var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
            var footstr = "</body>";
            var newstr = document.all.item(div_print).innerHTML;
            var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
    <title>div print</title>
</head>

<body>
   
    <input name="b_print" type="button" class="ipt" onClick="printdiv('div_print');" value=" Print ">

    <div id="div_print">

        <h1 style="Color:Red">The Div content which you want to print</h1>

    </div>
    
</body>

</html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCb6w.jpg
````

Comment: Have you tried setting `margin:0` on the `div`?

Comment: yes i used it. but it didn't work. same space is comming. @scott Marcus

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
@media print {
     body {
        margin: -2rem 0 0 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: thankyou @jkarttunen. i tried it. but still the top space is comming. i don't know what happen exactly.

Comment: Try negative top margin next?